# Python combining for and if conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here are the given values:

```
v = 1, w = 1, x = 1, y = 0, z = 1
j = 0, k = 1, l = 0, m = 0, n = 0, o = 0, p = 0

chked = [v, w, x, y, z]
unchked = [j, k, l, m, n, o, p]
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
for a in chked:
   if a != 1
   or
for b in unchked:
   if b != 0:
Then only Do something. (change those element's value etc.)
```

Comment: What is (a) and (b)?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question by giving an example how you would do it using `for` loops and `if` conditions?

Comment: @corinna just edited that.

Comment: Provide some examples. It's not clear. Is `chked` and `uncked` two lists? if so, list of what? Numbers?

Comment: You can use the [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) method to check if there is a 0 in chked, respectively a 1 in unchked.

Comment: Let me be more specific:
chked = [v, w, x, y, z]
unchked = [j, k, l, m, n,o, p]
for a in range(len(chked)):
if chked[a] != 1 or unchked[a] != 0:

Comment: @Kamal, what thing in particular do you want to do with inside the loop?

Comment: Do I understand correct, that you want to find elements from `a` not equal to `1` and elements from `b` not equal to `0` and perform the same action on them?

Comment: @ John, just want to make sure that all the elements in chked should be 1 (or not 0) and for unchked all the elements should be 0:
if not so:
call a pre define function.

Comment: @bereal, yes you got it correctly. What could be the snippet?

Comment: @Kamal that depends on what you want to do with those elements.

Answer (score 3):

Since what you want to do is vague, i'll have to make some assumptions. If you are dealing with arrays with values limited to 1s and 0s, and you want to "do something" when there are 1s or 0s when they shouldn't be there, you can do this:

```
v, w, x, y, z = 1, 1, 1, 0, 1
j, k, l, m, n, o, p = 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

# I assume you have reasons for storing each value separately from the list
chked = [v, w, x, y, z]
unchked = [j, k, l, m, n, o, p]

if not all(chked) or any(unchked):
    DoSomething()
```

`not all(chked)` will check if not all elements are 1s. That is, some 0s exists in chked.
While `any(unchcked)` will check if there exists any `1` among the 0s.

However, If you want to do something on the elements which are different,
you can do this:

```
new_chcked = [DoSomethingOnA(a) if a == 0 else a for a in chcked]
new_unchcked = [DoSomethingOnB(b) if b == 1 else b for b in unchcked]
```

Comment: "*Since what you want to do is vague*" -> you shouldn't answer, but try to make OP give a proper problem statement. Otherwise you risk a future edit to the question invalidating your answer (and you perpetuate crappy asking behaviours by giving lazy askers what they need).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `comprehension list` like follows:

```
if not [elt for elt in chked if elt == 0]
or not [elt for elt in unchked if elt == 1]):
    #do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to find all elements that fulfill a condition?

```
not_one = filter(lambda x: x!=1, chked) 

# or in python3
not_one = list(filter(lambda x: x!=1, chked))
```

or do you have two lists of the same length and want to search for pairs (that's what you wrote in the comment with `a in range(len(chked))`, but it doesn't fit to the question example)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, you may want to find where the rule of each checked/unchecked pair is violated.
then you can use the following code:

```
# Example
chked = [1, 1, 1, 1]
unchked = [0, 0, 0, 1]
for a in range(len(chked)):
if chked[a] != 1 or unchked[a] != 0:
    print "At index {0}: chked[{0}] = {1} \
           and unchcked[{0}] = {2}".format(a, chked[a], unchked[a])
```

Comment: @JohnTitusJungao, After reading his answer, I edited my question to be more specific.